# Splitting a string by '=' and receiving an array with a zero

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to process search results from my server. A user writes a search query into a field and the server returns a string containing pairs of article id=article title separated by newline. I'm splitting them around equals sign, but the result is an array with zero. I'm missing something obvious here.

```
function findArticle(){
    let input=document.getElementById("search")
    let value=input.value
    if(value){
        let request=new XMLHttpRequest()
        request.onreadystatechange=function (){
            if(request.readyState===4){
                let result=request.response
                if(result!==''){
                    let searchResults=document.getElementById('search-results')
                    let split=result.split('/\n/')
                    searchResults.innerHTML=''
                    for (const next in split) {
                        let parts=next.split("/=/")
                        console.log(parts)
                        searchResults.innerHTML+="<a href='"+parts[0]+"'>"+parts[1]+"</a>"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        request.open("GET","article-search.php?query="+value,true)
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send()
    }
}
```

article-search.php

```
<?php
include_once 'constants.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
$query=$_GET['query'];
$q="SELECT id,title FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$query%'";//;"SELECT id,title FROM defaultdb.articles WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('$query')";
$c=defaultMysqlConnection();
$results=executeQuery($c,$q,true);
if($results){
    foreach ($results as $result){
        echo $result['id']."=".$result['title']."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your string you're splitting surround the `=` with slashes?

Comment: You seem to be confused about splitting with a string vs a regex literal

Comment: Can you include the actual string (or an example int eh same format) that is returned from the server?

Comment: The split function in javascript accepts regular expressions and strings, you are apparently trying to use regular expressions, but you are reporting them as a string. Remove single and double quotes if you want to use regular expression. `split(/\n/)` and `split(/\=/)`.

Comment: If you are in control of the PHP, send the response as a JSON array of objects e.g. [{ id: string, title: string }] and parse it as JSON on the client.

Comment: You're trying to loop over an array using for-in. This will loop over the _indices_ of the array; use for-of to loop over elements.

Comment: So the reason you are getting an array with `0` instead of the expected: The first split operation results in an array, with the data the sole element; it is not split due to issues with your separator (see other comments). You then loop over the sole _index_ of this array, which is the string `0` (because keys are actually always strings). Calling `.split` on this returns an array with just it (as there was obviously nothing to split on. Thus: `['0']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code.

#### Separators

The separator you are trying to split on doesn't make sense. As mentioned in the comments, you seem to be confusing regular expressions with plain string separators.

Use `"\n"` and `"="` instead of `'/\n/'` and `"/=/"`.
You could use regular expressions (`/\n/` and `/=/`), but those are overkill for this.

#### Looping

You're trying to loop over an array using for-in. This will loop over the indices of the array; use for-of to loop over elements.

### Why `['0']`?

So, the reason you are getting `['0']` instead of the expected?

1. The first split operation results in an array, with the data the sole element; it is not split due to the issues with your separator.
2. You then loop over the sole index of this array, which is the string `0` (because keys are actually always strings).
3. Calling `.split` on this returns an array with just it (as there was obviously nothing to split on. Hence the `['0']`.

Comment: Yeah, incorrect looping was the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your PHP to return JSON data from the server.

```php
<?php
/* === Filename: article-search.php === */

// Check for existence of `query` parameter
if (!isset($_GET['query']) || empty($_GET['query'])) {
    print json_encode(array()); // Empty JSON array
    exit(0); // Halt script execution
}

// SQL query
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `article` WHERE `title` LIKE ?";

// Open a connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stackoverflow");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Title from GET request, and surround with percent symbols
$title = '%'.$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['query']).'%';

// Prepare, bind, execute
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $title);
$stmt->execute();

// Fetch an array of rows, store for encoding later
$rows = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 

// Close the connection
$conn->close();

// Set content type
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

print json_encode($rows); // Return JSON to the client

?>
```

Now you can parse the response on the client as JSON and simply loop over an array of book objects.

```js
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.response) {
  const searchResults = document.getElementById('search-results');
  const articles = JSON.parse(request.response);
  articles.forEach(article => {
    const { id, title } = article;
    searchResults.innerHTML += `<a href="${id}">${title}</a>`;
  });
}
```

**Note:** You should always use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks.

---

### Fetch API

Instead of using the outdated XHR object, try the newer Fetch API:

```js
fetch(`article-search.php?query=${value}`, {
  method: 'GET', // Default value, optional
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(articles => {
    const searchResults = document.getElementById('search-results');
    articles.forEach(article => {
      const { id, title } = article;
      searchResults.innerHTML += `<a href="${id}">${title}</a>`;
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Using slashes in the string you pass to split is incorrect.  When splitting on a simple string literal (as opposed to a regular expression), just pass the string literal unaltered.

```
let split=result.split('\n');
let parts=next.split('=');
```